# Is there a utility for unpacking Unity Engine meshes, textures, etc. and turning them into their original FBX and PNG files or equivalent, like .obj?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am an asset ripper for CREATIVE USE, not redistribution or reuse. I am looking for a program to rip the assets from Escape from Tarkov, but my PC freezes when I attempt it. I use AssetStudio (https://github.com/Perfare/AssetStudio). Is there anything like AssetStudio that can unpack a Unity Bundle (.bundle) and give me the source models and textures?

Comment: `CREATIVE USE` or not ... it doesn't sound quite legal .. if authors would want you to have access to their original source assets they would provide them to you ...

Comment: Im with DerHugo. Personal use or not its not overly legal

Comment: derHugo and BugFinder, I use the assets to make personal creations, e.g. videos, posters and short films. I do not redistribute or profit from such works. I give the works away for free. I have read Tarkov's EULA and I am in my right as a customer of BattleState Games to use the assets I have bought. I do not wish to come across as rude.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export meshes from unity (FBX) you can use Blender. Blender has a feature that allows you to import files such as FBX, OBJ, X3D (that includes the materials). [How to import files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt5tv.png) After you imported the files you can export them in a different format.

Comment: Thank you, but I already know how to use and operate Blender. I have it open right now as a matter of fact. What I'm trying to do is get the packed bundles of resources (.bundle) and export them into .FBX, .OBJ, .DAE, .PNG, etc. I know about Blender and its importing capabilities. I hope I do not come across as rude.